# Kendo UI web Grid field template

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

I have a table that has a Customers field statusId. StatusId CustomerStatuses in a table with fields ID and name. How to use a template, if I want to display a table filed name using ajax:

```
{
  field: "statusId", title: "Customer", with: 300,                    
  template: editTemplate
},

function editTemplate(row) {        
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Patients/GetGuids/",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                    if (value.id == row.statusId) {
                        return value; // return string
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code in jsFiddle or jsBin ?

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly what you're trying to accomplish, from your description. Could you clarify this, possibly by posting some example output?